# Good book for building high performance web sites?

Tags: linux, web-server, performance

Any recommendations for a book about building and running high performance, high-availability web sites on Linux?

Comment: look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/32963/website-recommendations/33052

Comment: What would a "right" answer to this look like?  I think this should be a community wiki question.

Comment: Yes, I actually made a mistake. I was going to add a bounty for another question but didn't notice before it was too late.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Theo Schlossnagle has a book called Scalable Internet Architectures which is excellent.

There's a list on highscalability.com here http://highscalability.com/book-store

Comment: The book-store moved to here: http://astore.amazon.com/possiboutpos-20

Answer (score 7):

Two of my favorites:

- Building Scalable Web Sites - Cal Henderson
- The Art of Capacity Planning: Scaling Web Resources - John Allspaw

Comment: +1 for Cal Henderson's book as the best introduction / 'overview of what you need to know' book. You can then later deep-dive into specific technologies as needed.

We should also mention http://highscalability.com/ as the primary news aggregator in this area.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what db you use I would highly recommend "[High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/)" if you go with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

use static html files or dynamic files that are heavily cached.

Install the following extensions for Firefox:

**Firebug**:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843

**Yslow**:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369

**Page Speed**:
http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

Yslow and Page speed will rate your current site, and tell you where your site needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of useful articles about high perfomance websites you can find at http://webo.name/articles/

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Rails](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596515201/) is a great resource for this and definitely goes beyond the scope of the title of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Building Scalable Web Sites (by Cal Henderson) and The Art of Capacity Planning (by John Allspaw) are two of my favourites.

Nowadays, I'm waiting for the long awaited "[Web Operations - Keeping the Data on Time](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920000136/)", by John Allspaw and Jesse Robbins, which will be released in June.